# Reading character files between specific word in java

Tags: java, java-io

I have a java file, FileJava.java like this:

```
public class FileJava {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    }
}
```

}

Then, i read above code line by line using this code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileReplace {
 List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
 String line = null;


public void  doIt() {
    try {
        File f1 = new File("FileJava.java");

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f1);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if (line.contains("for"))
                {
                    lines.add("long A=0;");

                    if(line.contains("(") && line.contains(")")){
                        String get = line;
                        String[] split = get.split(";");

                        String s1 = split[0];
                        String s2 = split[1];
                        String s3 = split[2];


                    }
            }
            lines.add(line);
        }
        fr.close();
        br.close();

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f1);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(String s : lines)
             out.write(s);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    FileReplace fr = new FileReplace();
    fr.doIt();

}
```

}

The question is, how to read character between '(' and ')' inside (for) in the FileJava.java, the character i mean "int i = 0; i < 5; i++" that will be stored in a variable, i have split based on ";", but when i print, the value :

```
s1 = for (int i = 0
s2 = i < 5
s3 = i++) {
```

While i expect:

```
s1 = int i = 0
s2 = i < 5
s3 = i++
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to get the correct `substring` before splitting.

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know how, any idea with this code: if(line.contains("(") && line.contains(")")){

Comment: @laune - please disregard. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are splitting on ';' for the input

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
```

which will return all the characters between ';'

You can write a new method, called getBracketContent for example, that will be something like

```
String getBracketContent(String str)
{
    int startIdx = str.indexOf('(')
    int endIdx = str.indexOf(')')

    String content = str.subString(startIdx + 1, endIdx);
}
```

then your code would be

```
if(line.contains("(") && line.contains(")")){
                    String get = getBracketContent(line);
                    String[] split = get.split(";");
```

Ideally I would use regular expressions to parse the information you need, but that is probably something you may want to look into later.

Comment: Waw, thanks :) It works !!, but i still confuse how the output file will be code format? After i read the file, the writing is not code format.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question how to restrict the splitting to the parenthesized section:

```
String[] split =
   get.substring( get.indexOf('(')+1, get.indexOf(')').split("\\s*;\\s*");
```

**Edit** to address another prob.

Printing of the file will all happen in one line, because BufferedReader.readLine strips the line ends (LF, CRLF) from the line it returns. Thus, add a line break when writing:

```
for(String s : lines){
    out.write(s);
    out.newLine();
}
```

Comment: Note the more robust pattern in split which omits spaces in the terms.

Comment: Alright, then would you tell me how the output will be code format (Java code format)? same with origin code before?

Comment: Added something to my answer to address what might be your prob.

Comment: i have tried your code, but nothing change happened ;-), Thanks

Comment: Quite likely - you haven't made clear what your "code format" ramblings mean. If you want to get output A, but you get B, from input C, you'll have to deposit A, B, and C here, so that readers know what you are talking about.

Comment: well, i am sorry, then just because i read java file, so the output should be seem like java code format, i add lines.add("\n"); based on your answer and it's look like more pretty, thanks. But i have another problem, i modify FileJava.java like this : for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { data[i]; }, when try with this :  if(line.contains("[") && line.contains("]")), it's not found, what the problem?

Comment: (a) There is no such line. (b) You have made an error where you don't think that there is an error. (c) Something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index1 = line.indexOf("(");
int index2 = line.indexOf(")");
line = line.subString(index1 + 1, index2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the contents of a java file, you would be much better off using an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) parser which will read in the contents of the file and then callback when it encounters certain expressions. In your case, you can listen just for the 'for' loop.

Comment: would you mind if you write an example using AST please? i have never tried before.

Comment: I believe that OP is on `Intro to Java` level.

Comment: Just because you're a beginner, doesn't mean you should do things the hard way:) @SamsulArifin - have a look here: http://www.programcreek.com/2011/01/a-complete-standalone-example-of-astparser/. It may be a bit beyond what you're used to, but manual parsing of Java files isn't a good idea.